# customized tab navigation with two tabs

Tags: react-navigation

using react-navigation I'm trying to build a tab navigation with 3 screens, one screen to be the `Main` screen which is showing the bottom tabs to other two screen that is `Filter` and `Sort` modal screen. right now, I can't do this with `createBottomTabNavigator` as it switches between screen and that tabs is added in all screens.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a regular stack navigator and in this navigator you should use the other 'main' tab navigator. Something like:

```
const App = createStackNavigator();

<App.Navigator>
  <App.Screen name="TABNAVIGATORS" component={TABNAVIGATORS} />
</App.Navigator>
```

Then, on the TABNAVIGATORS component you create as you wish:

```
const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

<Tab.Navigator>
            <Tab.Screen
                name="Home"
                component={MainScreen}
                options={{
                    tabBarLabel: '',
                    tabBarIcon: () => <Entypo name="home" size={24} color="#FFF" />,}}
            />
...

 </Tab.Navigator>
```